# What goes wrong with my Pandas Read_JSON for a simple API?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, api

I am using a simple method to call some surfing data from MSW with the following code:

```
import requests

spot = requests.get('http://magicseaweed.com/api/{API_KEY}/forecast/?spot_id={SPOT_ID}&units=eu')
```

Converting spot to JSON with: `spotJson = spot.json()`
Returns a `list` like this:

```
[{"timestamp":1587772800,"localTimestamp":1587772800,"issueTimestamp":1587772800,"fadedRating":0,"solidRating":0,"swell":{"absMinBreakingHeight":0.22,"absMaxBreakingHeight":0.35,"probability":100,"unit":"m","minBreakingHeight":0.2,"maxBreakingHeight":0.3,"components":{"combined":{"height":0.6,"period":4,"direction":178.94,"compassDirection":"N"},"primary":{"height":0.6,"period":4,"direction":183.14,"compassDirection":"N"}}},"wind":{"speed":22,"direction":196,"compassDirection":"NNE","chill":2,"gusts":25,"unit":"kph"},"condition":{"pressure":1016,"temperature":8,"weather":"11","unitPressure":"mb","unit":"c"},"charts":{"swell":"https:\/\/charts-s3.msw.ms\/archive\/wave\/750\/7-1587772800-1.gif","period":"https:\/\/charts-s3.msw.ms\/archive\/wave\/750\/7-1587772800-2.gif","wind":"https:\/\/charts-s3.msw.ms\/archive\/gfs\/750\/7-1587772800-4.gif","pressure":"https:\/\/charts-s3.msw.ms\/archive\/gfs\/750\/7-1587772800-3.gif","sst":"https:\/\/charts-s3.msw.ms\/archive\/sst\/750\/7-1587772800-10.gif"}}]
```

I use this `list` to loop through and get me the moment when it is good for a surf :)! BUT I would love to put the data into Pandas using the read_JSON method from Pandas to enrich my data with other forecasts:

```
import pandas as pd

raw = pd.read_json(spot)
```

For which I get the following error:

```
invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

I can get it into a Dataframe using the following method:

```
pd.DataFrame(spotJson)
```

But I just want to know why I can't do it directly from Pandas, which would make more sense since this option is available. Any thoughts on why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To normalize nested data like this you need to use `json_normalize`. For `pandas` older than version `1.0` use `pd.io.json.json_normalize`, otherwise use `pd.json_normalize`.

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
```

OR

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

Columns are labeled as their path inside the JSON, i.e a nested dictionary in your JSON will have `parent_key.child_key` notation.

```
df.columns

Index(['charts.period', 'charts.pressure', 'charts.sst', 'charts.swell',
       'charts.wind', 'condition.pressure', 'condition.temperature',
       'condition.unit', 'condition.unitPressure', 'condition.weather',
       'fadedRating', 'issueTimestamp', 'localTimestamp', 'solidRating',
       'swell.absMaxBreakingHeight', 'swell.absMinBreakingHeight',
       'swell.components.combined.compassDirection',
       'swell.components.combined.direction',
       'swell.components.combined.height', 'swell.components.combined.period',
       'swell.components.primary.compassDirection',
       'swell.components.primary.direction', 'swell.components.primary.height',
       'swell.components.primary.period', 'swell.maxBreakingHeight',
       'swell.minBreakingHeight', 'swell.probability', 'swell.unit',
       'timestamp', 'wind.chill', 'wind.compassDirection', 'wind.direction',
       'wind.gusts', 'wind.speed', 'wind.unit']
```

If you need less columns or want it structured differently you'll have to pass in some arguments when you call this function. You can see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas-json-normalize) for more info.